# Does every homeomorphism of a compact metric space lift to the Cantor set?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems, cantor-set

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297435/does-every-continuous-map-between-compact-metrizable-spaces-lift-to-the-cantor-s).  It is well-known that any compact metrizable space can be expressed as a quotient of the Cantor set.  But can every homeomorphism of such a space be lifted to a homeomorphism of the Cantor set?

More precisely, let $K$ be a compact metric space, and let $h\colon K\to K$ be a homeomorphism.  Does there exist a quotient map $q\colon C\to K$, where $C$ is the Cantor set, and a homeomorphism $\bar{h}\colon C\to C$ making the following diagram commute?
$$
\begin{array}{ccl}
C & \xrightarrow{\textstyle\;\;\;\bar{h}\;\;\;} & C \\[8pt]
q\left\downarrow\begin{array}{c}\! \\\! \end{array}\right. & & \left\downarrow\begin{array}{c}\! \\\! \end{array}\right.\!\!q \\[8pt]
K & \xrightarrow[\textstyle\;\;\;h\;\;\;]{} & K
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is true for actions of countable groups, and in particular for $\mathbb{Z}$-actions.

Let $C$ be a Cantor set and $G$ a countable group. Recall that $C^G$ is also a Cantor set. We let $\lambda:G\curvearrowright C^G$ denote the usual left action: $\lambda_g(f)(h)=f(g^{-1}h)$ for all $g,h\in G$ and $f\in C^G$.

Now, suppose that $G$ acts freely by homeomorphisms on a compact metric space $K$. Let $q:C\to K$ be a quotient map. Define the new space

\begin{align*}
D&=\left\{f\in C^G:\forall g\in G, q(f(g))=g^{-1}(q(f(1)))\right\}\\
&=\left\{f\in C^G:\forall g,h\in G, q(f(hg))=g^{-1}(q(f(h)))\right\}
\end{align*}

At this step, $D$ does not need to be a Cantor set, however it should be clear that $D$ is closed in $C^G$, hence compact, metrizable, zero-dimensional. The only point that might fail is perfectness, but we will deal with this later on.

Note that $D$ is $\lambda$-invariant, i.e., if $f\in D$ and $g\in G$ then $\lambda_g f\in D$.

Now, let $Q:D\to K$ be "evaluation at $1$ followed by $q$": $Q(f)=q(f(1))$. One easily checks that this is surjective, hence a quotient map, which is $(\lambda,G)$-invariant, i.e., $Q\lambda_g=gQ$ for all $g\in G$.

$$
\begin{array}{ccl}
D & \xrightarrow{\textstyle\;\;\;\lambda_g\;\;\;} & D \\[8pt]
Q\left\downarrow\begin{array}{c}\! \\\! \end{array}\right. & & \left\downarrow\begin{array}{c}\! \\\! \end{array}\right.\!\!Q \\[8pt]
K & \xrightarrow[\textstyle\;\;\;g\;\;\;]{} & K
\end{array}
$$

We would be done if $D$ was already perfect, but this might not me the case. To fix this, we simply consider $D'=D\times C$, which is a Cantor set, and extend the action of $G$ and the quotient map from $D$ naturally to $D'$, namely via $\lambda_g'(f,x)=(\lambda_gf,x)$ and $Q'(f,x)=Q(f)$ for all $(f,x)\in D'$. Then $D',\lambda'$ and $Q'$ have the properties we want.

---

We can improve our previous result and show that (infinite) minimal systems are factors of Cantor minimal systems. By a *compact dynamical system* we mean a compact metric space $K$ endowed with an action of a countable group $G$ by homeomorphisms. A *subsystem* consists of a closed invariant subset $M$ of $K$, endowed with the restricted action. A (sub)system is called *minimal* if it does not have any nontrivial subsystems. A *Cantor system* is a compact dynamical system on the Cantor set.

**Lemma:** Suppose $(C,G)$ is a Cantor system and $M$ is a minimal (closed) subsystem. Then $M$ is either finite or a Cantor set.

*Proof:* The only problem is to show that $M$ is perfect. Since $M$ is a minimal subsystem, it is the closure of the orbit of any of its points. Suppose $M$ is not finite and let $x\in M$. Since $M=\overline{Gx}$, the orbit $Gx$ must be infinite and hence accumulates at some point, i.e., there exist a sequence of elements $g_n\in G$ such that $g_nx\neq g_mx$ for $n\neq m$, and $g_nx\to y$ for some $y\in M$. Let's analyse two cases separately:

*Case 1: $y\in Gx$.*

Then $y=hx$ for some $h$, so $\left\{h^{-1}g_nx\right\}$ is a sequence of distinct points which converges to $x$.

*Case 2: $y\not\in Gx$, or equivalently $x\not\in Gy$.*

Since $M=\overline{Gy}$, for any neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ there exists $h$ such that $hy\in x$, and $hy\neq x$ by hypothesis. *QED*

**Theorem:** Any infinite minimal compact dynamical system $(K,G)$ is a factor of a minimal Cantor system.

*Proof:* We already know that $(K,G)$ is a factor of a Cantor system, say $Q:C\to K$ is a quotient map. Let $(D,G)$ be a minimal subsystem of $(C,G)$. Since $Q$ maps orbits of $(D,G)$ to orbits in $(K,G)$, and the latter is minimal, the restriction $Q|_D:D\to K$ is surjective, so in particular $D$ cannot be finite, hence it is a Cantor set. In other words, $Q|_D$ is a quotient map from the Cantor minimal system $(D,G|_D)$ onto $(K,G)$. *QED*

Comment: Very nice!  By the way, is freeness ultimately required for anything other than proving that $D$ is perfect?  If so, it seems to me that it might be possible to remove that condition by simply replacing each isolated point of $D$ by a Cantor set.  This assumes that the set of isolated points of $D$ is $\lambda$-invariant, which ought to be the case.

Comment: @JimBelk Yes. Actually my proof that $D$ is perfect was not correct, since the metric I considered did not actually make $\lambda_g$ an isometry. I tried to apply your suggestion and apparently it works.

Comment: @JimBelk I added a consequence, that every minimal infinite topological system is a factor of a minimal Cantor system. The finite case should be true as well, but I still don't know how to prove it in general. (For $\mathbb{Z}$ it is fairly easy: a minimal finite (compact) system consists of a finite set $K=\left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$ and a permutation $\psi=(1\ 2\cdots n)$. Take the odometer $\phi$ on $C=K^\mathbb{N}$, which is minimal, and the quotient $Q:C\to K$, $Q((x_n)_n)=x_0$).